# Build and run library on a Cortex M3 using KEIL uVision IDE

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, crypto++

I want to use the Crypto++ library on an ARM cortex M3 microcontroller using the Keil uVision IDE.

How do I build and run library on a Cortex M3 using KEIL uVision IDE

Comment: Why don't you try it and then ask about any problems you have?  Otherwise this is going to attract down-votes or closure as it is speculative.

Comment: Because I don't know where to start. Otherwise I would have done it by myself

Comment: The answer to the question asked is probably "yes", although it might be "no". Either way, it illustrates how useful a question it is. The underlying reasoning might be anything from "How can I import an external project into uVision?" to "How can I solve <compilation error> building Crypto++ for Cortex-M?" to "Is an <x>MHz Cortex-M3 fast enough to run <crypto algorithm>?", so we have no idea which particular area of expertise is relevant. A specific question is answerable; vague leading questions merely hoping to entice someone knowledgable into a dialogue is not what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: @user1204481 : Of course but it is not unreasonable for you to have made an attempt.  Start by creating a generic Cortex-M3 library project in uVision and adding the source code to it.  Try building that and see what occurs - fix the issues,  ask specific question if you get stuck.  It may be worth looking at the GCC build makefile to see if there is anything special about the build.

Comment: @user1204481 - what board are you using? I'd like to pick one up for testing. I also need to add examples of running the test suite at Crypto++'s [ARM Embedded (Bare Metal)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_%28Bare_Metal%29)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the Crypto++ library on an ARM cortex M3 microcontroller using the Keil uVision IDE.

Crypto++ has a wiki page on cross-compiling for the platform. See [ARM Embedded (Bare Metal)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_%28Bare_Metal%29) on the Crypto++ wiki. It uses ARM/Terry Guo's cross-compiler, so it has the latest processor support.

Fro Cortex M3, you are going to want to add either `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3` or `-mthumb -march=armv7-m` to `CXXFLAGS`. You also need to link against the `armv7-m` multilib. (I'm not sure which C++ runtime is used).

There's also [ARM Embedded (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_%28Command_Line%29) on the Crypto++ wiki. But it uses Debian's cross tools, and they leave a lot to be desired at times.

Unfortunately, I know nothing about Keil uVision IDE, so I don't know where the pain points are.

---

> How do I build and run library

To build the library, you run `make static dynamic cryptest.exe`.

Once you build the library, you need to install `cryptest.exe` on the board, *in addition to* the test vectors and data in `TestVectors` and `TestData`.

You have to maintain the directory structure because the paths to the test data and vectors are hard coded. Once the board is loaded as so:

```
+ Filesystem
|
+ --- cryptest.exe
|
+ --- TestData/
|
+ --- TestVectors/
|
...
```

Then you simply run `./cryptest.exe v` to execute the tests.

But at 10 MHz to 150 MHz or so, the Cortex M3 is going to be quite painful :) Not to mention the memory pressures of a 3.5 MB binary on a resource contrained board....

You can fix the hard coded paths with the [DataDir Patch](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Datadir). Its provided by the community, but I think it should be part of the library. It cause every distro maintainer I know troubles.

---

> Has anyone tried it before?

Probably, but not that I am aware. If you get results, then please report back. I lack an exemplary platform, so I could not add typical results to the wiki page.